# Cartoon/cartoon images/cartoony images/cartoonish images

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Could someone please tell me which of the following phrases is the best?

> 1. They used real images instead of cartoon.
> 2. They used real images instead of cartoon images.
> 3. They used real images instead of cartoony images
> 4. They used real images instead of cartoonish images.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult one to answer because "cartoon" and the related adjectives you are asking about can be used in different ways.

*A* cartoon can refer to either:

- a single-frame, humorous drawing
- a short multi-frame strip, like the kind found in newspapers (longer strips are usually called 'comics' or 'comic-books')
- an animated tv or film feature

Traditionally, cartoons depict people or animals in humorously exaggerated ways - for example, people often have large eyes or disproportionate bodies; animals are often anthropomorphised. However, some artwork in comic books and animations eschews this style and attempts to be more realistic and/or feature anatomically correct characters.

Adjectives like "cartoony", or "cartoonish" tend to be used to describe the exaggerated style of drawing - that is, to describe a drawing or depiction which is not realistic. Even a cartoon could be described as "cartoony" if it uses that particular style.

So the answer to your question depends on what you are trying to say. If you are describing a piece of art that uses photos instead of drawings - perhaps a composite image - then arguably this *is* "a cartoon". You should perhaps say that it "uses photos rather than drawings".

If instead you are trying to describe a live-action film feature and state that it is not an animation, you should perhaps say that it "*is* a live-action film, not a cartoon (or an animation)".

If I have not covered what you are trying to describe please add detail to your question or in comments and I will try and address it.

Answer (score 1):

I think Astralbee has covered it. I would only add that if you choose sentence 1, you might want to pluralize "cartoon" as in "They used real images instead of cartoons" - if, of course, that is your meaning.

You could also simplify sentences 2 through 4 by saying, "They used real rather than cartoon images." That way you do not have to repeat the word "images". That strikes me as a cleaner sentence.

Looking through the various online dictionaries, "cartoonish" appeared more often than "cartoony". To be on the safe side I would use that word if you have to decide between them.

"They used real rather than cartoonish images" might be a good choice to consider.